# Powershell MSBuild error

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am trying to convert some of my old batch files that run MSBuild into PowerShell scripts. Researching the `Invoke-MSBuild` command, the code below is what I came up with:

```
Invoke-MsBuild -Path "C:\path\solution.sln" -MsBuildParameters "/target:Clean;Rebuild /property:Configuration=Release;Platform=""x64"" /fl /flp:verbosity=normal;logfile=C:\path\logfile.log" -KeepBuildLogOnSuccessfulBuilds
```

Looking at the log file, when I run the script it starts building the solution file with MSBuild but I keep getting this error:

> error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.

I am very confused because I have Visual Studio 2013 which uses the 12.0 platform. I tried reinstalling the v120 build tools but nothing changed.

Comment: Does your old batch script still work on the same machine? What does the batch command look like?

Comment: @sburgess123 Yes the old batch script still works:

    msbuild.exe C:\path\solution.sln /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64

Comment: @StewC where do you launch your old batch file from? That is, are you launching it from a Visual Studio command prompt? Are you running any setup before it runs?

Comment: Nope no setup before it runs. I just call my batch file from the regular cmd command prompt to run it and it builds fine.Also, the msbuild.exe I call for my batch script is from the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin" directory (using the same 12.0 platform that I want the Powershell script to use)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your PowerShell environment does not contain the proper environment variables (particularly %PATH%, or $env:Path in PowerShell). Fortunately, it's easy to confirm this is the case:

- Open the Visual Studio 2013 command prompt
- Run powershell
- Run your `Invoke-MsBuild` command

If it runs using those steps, then your solution is either:

1. Fiddle with powershell environment by editing your profile file (run `$profile` in powershell to find the path). For instance, the path can be modified by adding the line `$env:Path = $env:Path + ';another_path;yet_another_path'`
2. Find the batch file that is called by the Visual Studio 2013 command prompt - create a new batch file that calls that, then invokes powershell, so that your powershell environment is configured before powershell actually runs.

Comment: Have you tried running both x86 and x64 powershell?